# Change labels of equations in align to roman numbers

Tags: align, roman-numerals

Is there a way to make align label equations by roman numbers?

E.g. instead of labels (3.1),(3.2),(3.3) I would like to have (i),(ii),(iii)

[image: badly labeled equations]

Thanks for a help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250399/184389) answers your question, just use `\roman` instead of the suggested `\arabic` or `\alph`.

Comment: @KersouMan Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the equation numbers are generated using:

```
\def\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
```

This should be changed to:

```
\def\theequation{\roman{equation}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works!